# Is blockchain suitable for this application?

Tags: security, blockchain

We are trying to build a automobile health monitoring system based on blockchain where  data from sensors present in cars will be stored using blockchains.
Is this approach right or should we opt for a distributed database which has features of blockchain?

Answer (score -1):

Blockchain is not the best approach here. For the most part blockchain is a fad that will fade within three years. What you should do here is hire a bunch of mechanics to constantly inspect the cars and input the information into a google doc.

Edit: Sorry guys. A troll (a.k.a. my little brother) hacked into my computer (a.k.a. opened Chrome) and posted this. I didn't even know it was here until Joe McMahon commented on it. 1,000 apologies and all that.

Now in regards to the question, blockchain is basically a distributed database, so a distributed database with features of blockchain would be, in effect, blockchain. If you don't know much about blockchain, here is a page with some *very* basic info on blockchain https://blockgeeks.com/guides/what-is-blockchain-technology/

In your case, I don't think that blockchain is necessary or even practical. . . Unless you're actually a representative of a major car company and are thinking of implementing blockchain to make your cars better in which case I would say, "Yes, use blockchain."

Comment: This is certainly a creatively different option, but it's more opinion than answer. From the question, the asker has already invested in the sensors and probably the monitoring; they really need an answer as to how to store the data securely and dependably. A Google doc is probably not going to scale as a production system if there are more than a few cars and a few people editing the document.